# How to view Git repository in GitHub GUI after it was created in Git Shell (Windows)?

Tags: git, shell, github

I am a Git noob and I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/how-to-use-git-to-version-your-writing.html), which uses command line to set up a a repository. Everything is going well except for I would like to go "off track" from the tutorial and see how my repository looks like in the Github GUI.

Unfortunately when I open the GitHub GUI and try to add the repository I made in GitHub Shell, I get the message: "**Repository with same name already exists at this location**"

Certainly it does already exist - and obviously I am trying to recreate it rather than add it to the GitHub GUI view.

How can I go about adding a view of a repository in the GUI version of Github if it was made in Git Shell? I only see two options when I press the "+" plus sign at the upper left of the GitHub GUI Window: Create and Clone....

Comment: According to the [GitHub for Windows help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-repositories-with-github-for-windows/) you should be able to "add any repository already on your hard drive by dragging the folder in from Explorer. If that folder is a Git repository, GitHub for Windows will import all of the history and connect it to your GitHub account."

Comment: thanks - indeed this is the answer! (if you write is up as one I can accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GitHub for Windows help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-repositories-with-github-for-windows/) you should be able to

> add any repository already on your hard drive by dragging the folder in from Explorer. If that folder is a Git repository, GitHub for Windows will import all of the history and connect it to your GitHub account